# Run Python from existing Cocoa app

Tags: python, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, pyobjc

I have some python scripts and I'd like to create a Cocoa app using Xcode 6 to run python code by pressing some buttons. I have found [this](http://blog.adamw523.com/os-x-cocoa-application-python-pyobjc/) article which helped me a lot. I created a simple .nib file with push buttons and my code is running on each push.

What I want to do is to create a project entirely on Xcode to be able to add more features in my program besides executing python script.

[Here](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/tutorials/embedded.html) there is a tutorial about adding python to existing ObjC app but it didn't helped me. On stage 3 it says:

"...Select the Class View, NSObject, subclass as ITunesCommunication. Give the class an askITunes: action. Instantiate the class as object ITunesCommunication..."

Could someone explain that?
Is there any template or example code for Xcode 6? (I only found for Xcode 4 and 5)